# A message was typed into my Messages app (remotely?) but not sent

Tags: messages

A message showed up in my iPhone Messages app, typed into the "new message" box but not sent. I did not type it in or said those words for the microphone to hear. It seems to have been entered remotely. It was not sent. I have an iPhone 6. I'm connected to an iPad Pro, and an iPad by Bluetooth, by WiFi, and have AirDrop. I erased the message after I took a screenshot, but it just looks like any other text message waiting to be sent. The text stream was between me and my wife, and she has iPhone Plus and an iPad. Is someone remotely accessing my text messaging, and why type in a short sentence and then not send it?

Comment: In what sort of network environment do you used these devices? Any public networks (Starbucks, Wal*Mart, Dunkin' Donuts)? Corporate Wifi? How secure is your home network? WPA2 connections at a minimum?

Comment: It's more likely you were in a different app, typing, and didn't realize the front most app was messages.